# No database created

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rake

`rake db:create` doesn't return any errors but no database is created.
When I run `rake db:migrate`, I get the error message "rake aborted, unknown database".

I'm using MySQL2, Rails 2.3.11, Ruby 1.9.2

And here are the contents of my database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: diana_development
  username: root
  password:
  port: 3306
  host: localhost
```

My temporary solution is to create the database manually, and the the rake db:migrate runs fine. But this problem is bugging me and I want to know what's really wrong. Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 1):

try to use rake `db:create` first

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow! Note that @cancelledout specified in the second line of his or her question _rake db:create doesn't return any errors but no database is created_. Any ideas why it wouldn't return errors _and_ not create a database?

Comment: rake db:create --trace and gem list would give more source for thinking

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this problem has something to do with the change in `yaml` parsers from syck to psych between ruby-1.8 and ruby-1.9.

I have run into this myself but, as yet, have no solution to the difficulty.

If you switch to 1.8.7 (using rvm for instance) and run your rake `db:tasks` then I expect that they will work. This is what I am doing as a work around for now.